# codeigniter return null from json controller url

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

codeigniter return null from json controller url!!

this my json file controller:

```
function data()
{


    $var1 = array(
    'key_name1' => 'value_name1',
    'key_name2' => 'value_name2'
    );


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $encode_data = json_encode($var1);
    echo $encode_data;


}
```

and this is result controller:

```
function test()
{


    $decode_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('http://tickets.eritreaevents.com/agent/data')), true);
    print_r($decode_data);

}
```

Comment: I tried browsing your URL, http://tickets.eritreaevents.com/agent/data, and instead of getting JSON data I was redirected to a sign-in page.  Maybe that is what is happening with your file_get_contents call.  Try print_r the results of file_get_contents (before you do trim and json_decode).

Answer (score 0):

Update your `test` method like this

```
function test()
{
    // $url = 'http://tickets.eritreaevents.com/agent/data'; 
    $url = 'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=english&fields=photoUrl,description&limit=20';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $decode_data = json_decode($content, true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($decode_data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

[Sample JSON Url](https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=english&fields=photoUrl,description&limit=20)

Comment: I think the url link is does not have any json data. 
For testing purpose, can you try replacing url with `$url = 'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=english&fields=photoUrl,description&limit=20';`, and see if you get any data or response.

Comment: if you open that link in browser, you should see the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problems with authorization. Are you sure, application is logged in. 
Same as BareNakedCoder I was redirect to login page. So maybe there is other way of auth, e.g basic auth or API token ?
But if you received any data, please show it by

```
print_r($file_get_contents('http://tickets.eritreaevents.com/agent/data'));
```

or use cURL:

```
$s = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://tickets...');
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
// curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass); // Basic Auth
$data = curl_exec($s);
print_r($data);
curl_close($s);
```